# python thread exception errors when exit the whole program

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, wxpython

HI, guys,

I am developing a GUI with python 2.4.3 and wxpython. Everything works fine except when I exit main program(close the main window of GUI). The wierd thing is that sometimes there is such error, sometimes there is no error at all. Although I found the same error reports from the python mailing list(the link is http://bugs.python.org/issue1722344, I am not sure if my case is the same as this one). I do not know how it is finally solved and what I should do to overcome this problem.

The error message from the console is as follows.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 442, in __bootstrap
  File "/opt/company/workspace/username/application/src/mainwidget.py", line 1066, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/Queue.py", line 89, in put
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 237, in notify
exceptions.TypeError: exceptions must be classes, instances, or strings (deprecated), not NoneType
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

The following is part of my code(the thread related code is complete, I extract the main operations for the rest). when I use the GUI to launch an external subprocess, at the same time, a wx.TextCtrl object is created. This wx.TextCtrl object is used to give input and print output of the external subprocess

```
class BashProcessThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, readlineFunc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.readlineFunc = readlineFunc
        self.lines = []
        self.outputQueue = Queue.Queue()
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
           line = self.readlineFunc()
           self.outputQueue.put(line)
           if (line==""):
            break
        return ''.join(self.lines)

    def getOutput(self):
        """ called from other thread """            
        while True:
            try:
                line = self.outputQueue.get_nowait()
                lines.append(line)
            except Queue.Empty:
                break
        return ''.join(self.lines)

class ExternalProcWindow(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent, externapp):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, -1, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(1200, 120))
        self.externapp=externapp
        self.prompt = externapp.name.lower() + '>>'
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', size= wx.Size(1200, 120), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.default_txt = self.textctrl.GetDefaultStyle()
        self.textctrl.AppendText(self.prompt)
        self.outputThread = BashProcessThread(self.externapp.sub_process.stdout.readline)
        self.outputThread.start()
        self.textctrl.SetFocus()
        self.__bind_events()         
        self.Fit()

    def __bind_events(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.__enter)

    def __enter(self, e):
        nl=self.textctrl.GetNumberOfLines()
        ln =  self.textctrl.GetLineText(nl-1)
        ln = ln[len(self.prompt):]     
        self.externapp.sub_process.stdin.write(ln+"\n")
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.textctrl.AppendText(self.outputThread.getOutput())

class ExternApp:
    def launch(self):
        self.sub_process = subprocess.Popen(launchcmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the use of `threading.Thread.setDaemon`. Threads set daemonic don't prevent the Python intepreter from exiting, but *they still keep running*. Because Python cleans up the environment before the process is terminated, the threads can run into trouble when stuff is removed from under them. That raises an exception, which the thread class tries to print for your convenience -- but that, then, too fails because the process is exiting.

You could try to silence the exception, but that's tricky (and if the thread does anything substantial, it might hide a real problem. Not the case here, though.) Or you could ask the thread to stop *before* exiting, and not set the thread daemonic. Or you can simply avoid using threads altogether. I do not remember if wxPython has a convenient mechanism for getting a process's output or even of doing asynchronous I/O, but many GUI toolkits do. And there's always Twisted, which does it all for you.

Comment: HI, Thomas, thank you for your answer. I also tried not using thread, but I do not know how it can be done. how to stop a non-daemonic thread before process exits in python? also how to silence the exception without changing the theadiing.py

Comment: Usually, you communicate between threads using `Queue.Queue`s or `threading.Event` objects. You could use an event to tell the thread to stop reading lines, for example. In this case, you can also just check the returnvalue of the readline function; if it returned "", the process you started exited, and the thread should just stop. You can then get the thread to end by terminating the process it's reading output from.

Comment: hi, Thomas, when I close the program, I overwrite the OnClose Function (first terminate external process, and call self.destroy() to close the main window). unfortunately, the external process is always running until when I terminate it. so how to stop the thread?  In python, i did not find any function could directly terminate the thread. and also why sometimes there is this error and sometimes no error?

Comment: You can't terminate a thread from outside the thread. All you can do is make it exit. For example, using one of the mechanisms I already described (and having the thread stop when the readline function returns '' is a good idea regardless.) You only see the error sometimes because threads are unreliable and hard to control; they run when they want to, and only sometimes does a thread want to run exactly between the destruction of the environment it sees and the actual termination of the process. A little earlier or a little later and you don't see anything bad (but it's still there.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Thomas, let me first make a click for your answer is useful. I tried your good idea "thread exits when the readline function returns" in my code(see the revision in BashProcessThread.run(self) function). Is it what you mean? I will test it. Still what if the external running program stdout "", then is it a false alarm?

Comment: `file.readline` will only ever return `''` if the file hits EOF. For a process's stdout that means the process closed it, or terminated. Either way, after that happens there's no point in continuing to read data. The thread should end. Your new code looks sensible, except for `return ''.join(self.lines)`, which is pointless -- the returnvalue from `Thread.run` is ignored. Don't forget to remove the `setDaemon` call as well.